# How to restrict Multiline edittext to single line after typing is finished in Android?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-edittext, android-xml

I am using multiline EditText. After typing is finished and touch on another view,I want the editText to be appearing only one line. How to do it?

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/descriptionfield"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    />
```

Comment: Is there anything you tried so far... ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `setOnFocusChangeListener` to your edittext like following

```
 descriptionfield.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    descriptionfield.setSingleLine(false);
                } else {
                    descriptionfield.setSingleLine(true);
                }
            }
        });
```

If edittext has focus then `setSingleLine` to `false` else `setSingleLine` to `true`

I hope this helps you